# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named after renaming parent folder

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-import, pythonpath, sys.path

I have problems importing a local package I developed. I'm using **WSL** with a conda environment. I have the following structure:

```
 parent folder
     |- local_package
        |- package
           |- ...
           |- ...
        |- scripts
           |-script.py
```

Previously, with `/parent folder/local_package` as working directory, I could call `python scripts/script.py`, which imports my package and executes its main function. After some time, I have renamed the `parent folder` to `parent_folder`. After doing this rename, my script is no longer able to import my package, and shows `ModuleNotFoundError`. My current workaround consists in installing my package with pip, but installing it each time I need to test it or use the package while I'm modifying it is cumbersome.

My question is, how can I fix this problem so I'm able to run my script again without installing the package?

Some information that may be useful:

- Before renaming the folder I installed the package. This could maybe create some kind of cache
- I erased all `__pycache__` files within my `package` folder and my `scripts` folder to try solve the problem. Didn't work.
- Reinstalling and erasing the package doesn't solve the problem.
- My package uses `__init__.py` files. It also has a `setup.py` for installing it.
- My specific python version is 3.6.8 .
- This is the output of `print(sys.path)`:

`['', '/home/user/anaconda3/envs/p369_TF2.4/lib/python36.zip',  '/home/user/anaconda3/envs/p369_TF2.4/lib/python3.6',  '/home/user/anaconda3/envs/p369_TF2.4/lib/python3.6/lib-dynload',  '/home/user/anaconda3/envs/p369_TF2.4/lib/python3.6/site-packages',  '/mnt/c/Users/windows_user/Desktop/Parent folder/local_package']`

I suspect this can be fixed by modifying the PYTHONPATH environment variable, but it doesn't appear when I run `printenv` or in the windows environment variable window. I suppose that I could modify or add the path before importing my package, but I would prefer a cleaner way of doing it that doesn't require me to modify all future scripts.

Comment: I had somewhat same issue, deleting and re-creating the env worked. P.S - I renamed the parent dir while the env was active, maybe that was the issue for me.